# Preventing LaTeX from starting a new page before \begin{figure}

Tags: graphics

I'm writing a document and want to include an appendix of pictures at the end. Each picture has a caption associated with it, and a label. However, each time I try to compile the code, LaTeX automatically creates a page break between the section heading and the first figure. I know that use of \includegraphics can create a page break, but even if I use the figure environment without a picture as below, LaTeX starts a new page between the section heading and caption. Any ideas how I can stop this from happening?

```
\section{Appendix A}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption*{BlaBlaBla}
    \label{pic1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Comment: Hi @texenthusiast I've already tried this, e.g. using [!ht], but it does not work

Comment: If you don't want the image to move _don't_ put it in a figure environment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - what do you suggest?

Comment: NB, I have also tried using the afterpage package

Comment: just use `\includegraphics` directly. If you also want to caption it (which isn't really needed for a non floating figure) use `\captionof{figure}{my caption here}` from the capt-of or caption packages. The _only_ reason to use `figure` is to allow latex to move the figure.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - how does the figure labeling work in this case for reference in the rest of the document?

Comment: `\captionof` is identical to `\caption` except that you can use it outside the figure environment. (the whole package is just one line of code that defines \captionof to call \caption, so any labelling or caption styling works as required)